# Advise for form CSS in Wordpress

Tags: forms, css-float, gravity

I have a WP 3.2.1 site and use Gravity Forms 1.6.2 plugins. I make my first form, and the preview looks good ([www.censin.com/form-preview.jpg](http://www.censin.com/form-preview.jpg))

But when view in actual page, the second input text field (Official Website) is not float to the right side of first input text (Company Name). Image in [www.censin.com/form-live.jpg](http://www.censin.com/form-live.jpg)

You can visit the live page at: (protected page password: demo)
http://www.censin.com/marketplace/buyer-request/

I am not good at CSS styling, and I think the problem is in the theme style.css but i can't figure it out using firebug in firefox.
Seems like the last column of li is not define well and can't float to the right, or because the site theme css is do not have a usual definition for form input.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the wrapping is that the list items are slightly too big to floated next to each other so are being pushed down.

In your CSS file add a new rule to set the width on the UL element.

```
#gform_fields_1
{
    width:922px;
}
```

Comment: Although can't make the width fix in #gform_fields (it's gravity forms css for every forms layout), I will try to define the width elsewhere.